# Как структурировать массив объектов через reduce?

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться с reduce.
Есть массив объектов

```
[
  {
    "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 1",
    "rank":"Техник",
    "phone":"11111",
    "mainPhone":"88009006565",
    "description":"короткое описание",
    "category":{
      "name":"Категоря 1",
      "address":"Тут адрес 1",
      "position":100
    },
    "subCategory":{
      "name":"Подкатегория 1",
      "position":100
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 2",
    "rank":"Начальник",
    "phone":"22222",
    "mainPhone":"88009006564",
    "description":"короткое описание",
    "category":{
      "name":"Категоря 1",
      "address":"Тут адрес 1",
      "position":100
    },
    "subCategory":{
      "name":"Подкатегория 2",
      "position":200
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 3",
    "rank":"Техник",
    "phone":"22222",
    "mainPhone":"88009006564",
    "description":null,
    "category":{
      "name":"Категоря 1",
      "address":"Тут адрес 1",
      "position":100
      },
    "subCategory":{
      "name":"Подкатегория 1",
      "position":100
    }
  },
  {
    "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 3",
    "rank":"Техник",
    "phone":"22222",
    "mainPhone":"88009006564",
    "description":null,
    "category":{
      "name":"Категоря 2",
      "address":"Тут адрес 1",
      "position":100
      },
    "subCategory":{
      "name":"Подкатегория 1",
      "position":100
    }
  }
]
```

мне надо его структурировать примерно так

```
[
{
 name: ' Категория 1',
 subcadegory: [
  {
    name: 'Подкатегория 1',
    data: [
    {Тут массив объектов состоящий из данных людей которые входят в 1 категорию и 1 подкатегорию}
    ]
  }
 ]
}
]
```

Т.е по сути из имеющегося массива нужно создать массив объектов, каждый объект это отдельная категория, в котором будет вложен еще один массив объектов состоящий из подкатегорий, а уже в нем будут данные людей которые им принадлежат.
Никак не могу понять как это сделать через reduce, я уже пытался написать сам но далеко не продвинулся и ушел в другую степь

```
let a = arr.reduce((accum, current) => {
  if(accum.some((item) => Object.values(item).includes(current.category.name))){
    
  } else {
    accum.push({
      category: current.category.name
    });
  }
  
  return accum;
},[]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы на правильно пути, остается только немного додумать.

Для начала попробуйте сконцентрироваться на том, чтобы получить нужную иерархию верхнего уровня, перед тем как добавлять новый элемент. Вы правильно это начали делать, но пытаетесь вместо пошаговых действий соорудить один `if ... else`.

```js
let a = arr.reduce((accum, current) => {
  let categoryName = current.category.name;
  let subcategoryName = current.subCategory.name;
  
  // Проверить, есть ли уже категория в вашем accum и если её нет, добавить

  // Проверить, если уже подкатегория в вашем accum и если её нет, добавить
  
  // Получить из accum категорию, потом подкатегорию, потом добавить элемент
  
  return accum;
}, []);
```

Чуть больше подсказок можно получить тут

> ```js
> let a = arr.reduce((accum, current) => {
>       let categoryName = current.category.name;
>       let subcategoryName = current.subCategory.name;
>       
>       // Проверить, есть ли уже категория в вашем accum и если её нет, добавить
>       if (!accum.some(item => item.name === categoryName))
>         accum.push({ name : categoryName, subcategory : [] });
>       let category = accum.find(item => item.name === categoryName);
>
>       // Проверить, если уже подкатегория в вашем accum и если её нет, добавить
>       
>       // Получить из accum категорию, потом подкатегорию, потом добавить элемент
>       
>       return accum;
>     }, []);
> ```

Если все равно не поможет, то вот финальный вариант

> ```js
> var arr = [
>   {
>     "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 1",
>     "rank":"Техник",
>     "phone":"11111",
>     "mainPhone":"88009006565",
>     "description":"короткое описание",
>     "category":{
>       "name":"Категоря 1",
>       "address":"Тут адрес 1",
>       "position":100
>     },
>     "subCategory":{
>       "name":"Подкатегория 1",
>       "position":100
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 2",
>     "rank":"Начальник",
>     "phone":"22222",
>     "mainPhone":"88009006564",
>     "description":"короткое описание",
>     "category":{
>       "name":"Категоря 1",
>       "address":"Тут адрес 1",
>       "position":100
>     },
>     "subCategory":{
>       "name":"Подкатегория 2",
>       "position":200
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 3",
>     "rank":"Техник",
>     "phone":"22222",
>     "mainPhone":"88009006564",
>     "description":null,
>     "category":{
>       "name":"Категоря 1",
>       "address":"Тут адрес 1",
>       "position":100
>       },
>     "subCategory":{
>       "name":"Подкатегория 1",
>       "position":100
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "name":"Фамилия Имя Отчество 3",
>     "rank":"Техник",
>     "phone":"22222",
>     "mainPhone":"88009006564",
>     "description":null,
>     "category":{
>       "name":"Категоря 2",
>       "address":"Тут адрес 1",
>       "position":100
>       },
>     "subCategory":{
>       "name":"Подкатегория 1",
>       "position":100
>     }
>   }
> ]
>
> let result = arr.reduce(function(accum, current) {
>     let categoryName = current.category.name;
>     let subcategoryName = current.subCategory.name;
>     
>     if (!accum.some(item => item.name === categoryName))
>         accum.push({ name : categoryName, subcategory : [] });
>     let category = accum.find(item => item.name === categoryName);
>     if (!category.subcategory.some(item => item.name === subcategoryName))
>         category.subcategory.push({ name : subcategoryName, data : [] });
>     let subcategory = category.subcategory.find(item => item.name === subcategoryName);
>
>     subcategory.data.push(current)
>
>     return accum;
> }, [])
>
> console.log(result)
> ```

Дальше уже можете пробовать улучшать ваш код и оптимизировать, если есть такое желание.